# Arduino 1.8.7 Blink stuck on compiling iMac 10.14.1

Tags: java, arduino

Hi:  I am attempting to run the Blink sketch on my Arduino with IDE 1.8.7.  I seem to be stuck on compiling at the following point:

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/conorpower/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/conorpower/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/conorpower/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10807 -build-path /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/arduino_build_823983 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/arduino_cache_603529 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/untitled1719876965.tmp/sketch_dec02b/sketch_dec02b.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/conorpower/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/conorpower/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/conorpower/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10807 -build-path /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/arduino_build_823983 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/arduino_cache_603529 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/untitled1719876965.tmp/sketch_dec02b/sketch_dec02b.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr

Detecting libraries used...
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard /var/folders/sj/5xbm18s95jx6xry14qj2ftfh0000gn/T/arduino_build_823983/sketch/sketch_dec02b.ino.cpp -o /dev/null

Normally, I can work this out, but, I am really stuck on this one. It appears to have something to do with Java; I have the latest Java installed.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my issue; its not obvious:

Apple no longer include the Command Line Tools package in upgrades to the OS.  These are required to run Arduino and incidentally some Python editors.

Do the following:

1. Go to  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
2. Sign in.  Don't worry, just sign in with your Apple ID.  You don't have to be a developer.
3. In the list that follows search for the Command_Line_Tools package that corresponds to your Mac upgrade.  In my case it was for 10.14.
4. Download and install that package.  It may take a while to open this before it begins to install the package.
5. After that Arduino should run normally.